Declaring the constant variable with nodejs
How to declare the varibale in the nodejs to use through the node app.
import {
  SecretsManagerClient,
  GetSecretValueCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager';
import 'dotenv/config';
import logger from './utils/logger';
import { ENV_TYPE } from '@/constants/app';

// Declare secretsCache as a global variable
global.secretsCache = new Map<string, string | undefined>();

// console.log(global);

const loadFromAWSSecretManager = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const region = process.env.AWS_REGION || '';
  const secretId = process.env.SECRET_MANAGER_NAME || '';

  logger.info(
    `Fetching secrets from AWS secret manager with region: ${region} and secret manager name: ${secretId}`,
  );

  const client = new SecretsManagerClient({ region });

  try {
    const response = await client.send(
      new GetSecretValueCommand({ SecretId: secretId }),
    );

    if (!response.SecretString) {
      logger.warn('No secret string returned from AWS Secrets Manager.');
      return;
    }

    const secretsJson = JSON.parse(response.SecretString);

    for (const key in secretsJson) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(secretsJson, key)) {
        global.secretsCache.set(key, secretsJson[key]);
        logger.info(`Set secret for key ${key}: ${secretsJson[key]}`);
      }
    }

    console.log(global.secretsCache, 'global secrets');
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Error while fetching from AWS secret manager: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
};

// Load secrets from environment file
const loadFromEnvFile = (): void => {
  for (const key in process.env) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(process.env, key)) {
      global.secretsCache.set(key, process.env[key]);
    }
  }

  logger.info(
    `Secrets cache after loading from env file: ${JSON.stringify([...global.secretsCache.entries()])}`,
  );
};

// Initialize secrets based on the environment
const initialize = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || ENV_TYPE.DEVELOPMENT;

  if (env === ENV_TYPE.LOCAL) {
    loadFromEnvFile();
  } else {
    await loadFromAWSSecretManager();
  }

  logger.info(
    `Secrets cache after initialization: ${JSON.stringify([...global.secretsCache.entries()])}`,
  );
};

// Get a secret from the cache
const getSecret = (secretKey: string): string | undefined => {
  const secret = global.secretsCache.get(secretKey);

  console.log(global.secretsCache);

  logger.info(
    `Fetching sssssssssshhhhhhhhhhhs secret for key: ${secretKey} with complete secretCache: ${JSON.stringify([...global.secretsCache.entries()])}`,
  );

  // if (!secret) {
  //   throw new Error(`No Env variable found for ${secretKey}`);
  // }

  return secret;
};

console.log(global.secretsCache);

// Export the configuration object
export const environmentConfig = {
  initialize,
  getSecret,
};


I am trying the create the constant for the node js like this creating the constant and freezing
which work while comping with the nodemon but not working with ts-node
    "start:dev": "yarn swagger:gen && nodemon",
    "start": "node -r ts-node/register/transpile-only -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/src/index.js",


In index.js file I am using like this
import { environmentConfig } from './env';

const main = async () => {
  try {
    // Log the initial state of secretsCache
    console.log(
      environmentConfig.secretsCache,
      'secretsCache before initialization',
    );

    // Initialize environment configuration
    await environmentConfig.initialize();

    console.log('Environment initialized.');

    // Ensure that secretsCache is properly populated
    console.log(
      environmentConfig.secretsCache,
      'secretsCache after initialization',
    );

    console.log(environmentConfig.getSecret('DB_HOST'), 'from the index'); // Should output the secret value

    // Import additional initialization code
    await import('./initialize');

    // Fetch and log a secret
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing environment configuration:', error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

main();

export const config = environmentConfig;

Here if I try to get the data from the initialize file if I try to access the secret cache it reinitializes the variable return the empty string.
it work with the start:dev but does not work with start.
I tried using the skeleton pattern creating the class.
I guess it is due the ts-node compiling the file.
